# Wikipedia data via Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am new to beautiful soup and trying to pull some tables into a Python notebook. There are multiple tables at the site, but if I can get one working I think I can figure out the others. Have followed a few tutorials and think I must be missing something... maybe due to the `collapsible` class?

Here is my most recent attempt:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as r
import pandas as pd

uswnt_wiki_request = r.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_women%27s_national_soccer_team_results")
uswnt_wiki_text = uswnt_wiki_request.text

uswnt_soup = BeautifulSoup(uswnt_wiki_text, 'html.parser')

table = uswnt_soup.find('table', class_="wikitable collapsible collapsed")

df = pd.read_html(str(table))
df = pd.concat(df)
print(df)
```

Can somebody help nudge me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made several updates to your code.

1. You need to pass headers to get a proper response from Wikipedia.
2. You are trying to read all tables, but using `find` instead of `find_all`.
3. You need to clean headers/add headers, as per the table, the first three tables have a header and the last two don't and all of these have unnecessary double headers (Year range and color coding).

This is the final code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {
    'host': 'en.wikipedia.org'
}
response = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_women%27s_national_soccer_team_results").text
tables = bs(response, 'html.parser').find_all('table', class_="wikitable collapsible collapsed")

dfs = []
for table in tables:
    df = pd.read_html(str(table), skiprows=2)[0]

    if not 'Opponent' in df.columns:
        df.loc[-1] = df.columns
    
    df.columns = ['M', 'Opponent', 'Date', 'Result', 'Event']
    dfs.append(df)

combined = pd.concat(dfs)
print(combined)
```

Sample Output:

```
      M             Opponent             Date Result       Event
0     1                Italy  August 18, 1985    0–1  Mundialito
1     2              Denmark  August 21, 1985    2–2  Mundialito
2     3              England  August 23, 1985    1–3  Mundialito
3     4              Denmark  August 24, 1985    0–1  Mundialito
4     5               Canada     July 7, 1986    2–0    Friendly
..  ...                  ...              ...    ...         ...
57  721  Republic of Ireland   April 11, 2023    1–0    Friendly
58  722                Wales     July 9, 2023      –    Friendly
59  723              Vietnam    July 21, 2023      –   World Cup
60  724          Netherlands    July 26, 2023      –   World Cup
61  725             Portugal   August 1, 2023      –   World Cup

[725 rows x 5 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use attrs for finding it:

```
tables = uswnt_soup.find_all(attrs={'class', "wikitable collapsible collapsed"})
```

This is the go to solution when you find spaces in the class(es) tag of the element. The approach you tried first can only take one class name and regularly fails to find elements which have several.